# can't understand why i receive uncaught reference error function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to launch a Javascript function from PHP to initialize a module. Here is my code:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
$ParamArray[]='AdVisualV2jMODPHP_ver'; $ParamArray[]='0.3.0070'; // 000
$ParamArray[]='Station_ID'; $ParamArray[]=$params->get('Station_ID'); // 001
$ParamArray[]='Verbose'; $ParamArray[]=$params->get('Verbose'); // 002
$ParamArray[]='Bk_ColorODD'; $ParamArray[]=$params->get('Bk_ColorODD'); // 003
$ParamArray[]='Bk_ColorEVEN'; $ParamArray[]=$params->get('Bk_ColorEVEN'); // 004
$ParamArray[]='Ink_ColorODD'; $ParamArray[]=$params->get('Ink_ColorODD'); // 005
echo 'AVVIAMO LA PROCEDURA 0.0.095 - '.$Station_ID.'<br><br>';
echo '<div id="TabellaEventi"></div>';
$ParamArray = json_encode($ParamArray);
$ParamArray = htmlentities($ParamArray);
echo "<script language='javascript'>DisplayTable(0,15)</script>";
echo '<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Avanti" ONCLICK="avanti('.$ParamArray.')"> ';
echo '<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Indietro" ONCLICK="indietro('.$ParamArray.')"> ';
echo '<br>';
?>

<script>
Start = 0
Page = 15
// DisplayTable(Start,Page)

function avanti(Listaparametri) {
    Start=Start+Page+1
    DisplayTable(Start,Page)
}

function indietro(Listaparametri) {
    Start=Start-Page-1
    if (Start<0) {
        Start = 0
    }
    DisplayTable(Start,Page)
}

function DisplayTable(Inizio,Incremento) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            Esito=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open('GET','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/name.php?Start='+Inizio+'&Page='+Incremento,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    Esito='VISUALIZZAZIONE TABELLA<br>'+Esito+'<br><br>'
    document.getElementById('TabellaEventi').innerHTML=Esito;
}
</script>
```

I continue to receive the Uncaught Reference Error DISPLAYTABLE IS NOT DEFINED in the console when the page is loaded and have to call the DisplayTable javascript function, while it works perfectly if i remove the // in the script Javascript section. Of course i'm missing something and i can't understand what, thank you for any help (i'm a PHP/Javascript beginner, i apologize)

Answer (score 2):

As it says, DisplayTable is not defined when you call it. Declare the function BEFORE calling it. Usually you can call a function before it is declared, but in your case, you are calling it from a different script tag (enerated in your PHP).

Will not work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
test();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() { }
</script>
```

Will work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
test();
function test() { }
</script>
```

And also :

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is how you properly write a script tag.

You must be consistent when you write code, it will help you to find mistakes, and you will do much less mistakes too.

If you use :

```
bla bla {

}
```

Don't use

```
bla bla
    {

    }
```

somewhere else.

Don't forget semicolons ; after instructions. Keep a clear identation, etc.

Comment: hey. order of defining functions, doesn't matter in javascript. also <script> tag should work even without type attribute. you're siting much of semantics rather than actual solution to the OPs prblm

Comment: Then feel free to add a more constructive comment than your previous one. It does not work in this case because DisplayTable is called before being declared **AND** is called in a different script tag than the one it is declared in.

Comment: actually you are right. both are declared in different script tags. script tag defining the DisplayTable should be loaded earlier. +1

Comment: in any case, HOW can i declare it BEFORE?

Comment: Either declare it in your script tag generated by PHP, or put that script tag generated by PHP after the script tag here it is declared. Seems obvious.

Comment: To me seems that you are Sheldon